# Edittext input has lines around characters and won't delete

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext

I've been having an issue with edittexts in my app. I created them using the basic

```
etCurr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCurr);
etWorth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWorth);
etNeed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNeed);
```

but whenever I run the program and try to enter an input I get this issue

[image]

and when I try to delete the input, the current input does not go away.

Also, when I try to get the value of a edittext using

```
nWorth = Integer.valueOf(etWorth.getText().toString());
```

the app crashes.

Is this issue due to using Swiftkey or am I doing something else wrong?

EDIT: I also get this issue when I attempt to input into an edittext which is lower on the screen. This is the effect after the keyboard is closed.

[image]

Comment: When you are using this etWorth.getText().toString()  You need to make sure that your edittext don't have String character or empty strings

Comment: When I was testing it I only put in numbers. What is the best way to prevent a string input from crashing it?

Comment: For your Edittext set inputType=number

Answer (score 0):

Try it this one,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:singleLine="true"  <!-- use this single line -->
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: I placed everything inside of a relative layout. 

My edittexts looks like this
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNeed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvNeed"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

other than that I'm not really sure what else you may need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etCurr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:singleLine="true"  <!-- use this single line -->
    android:inputType="number" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

And then use this code for don't to delete characters from edit text,

```
    etCurr.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) { etCurrBeforeText=s.toString();
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable txt) {
}
});
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{   
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) 
    {   
        if(etCurr.hasFocus())
        {
             etCurr.setText(etCurrBeforeText);
        }
    }
}
```

then,

```
nCurr= Integer.valueOf(etCurr.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that you are describing. When I was typing in something after each letter a line appeared. After deleting the text you still could see the letters. Only after changing the orientation of the screen the view got updated. In my case I did the following to fix the bug:

My AndroidManifest.xml looked like this:

```
<application ..>
  <activity .. android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
  </activity>
</application>
```

I deleted the `android:theme` attribute as I accidentally added it once in the past and the problem was solved.